Why does the cart of an inverted pendulum move away from the pendulum on the downswing?
I am having trouble matching up the actual behavior of an inverted pendulum with it's free body diagram.
To me, it looks like when the pendulum is falling, the connector applies a tension (to keep the pendulum on its circular path) and pulls the pendulum towards the cart. Therefore, the tension will be opposite on the cart, like this, and the cart will be pulled/accelerate towards the ball because of the Tsinθ force.
In reality, when the ball falls, the cart moves LEFT, not RIGHT (in my diagram below). Why is this? See video I found for what it actually does.
Thanks!


Probably would be useful to think about the center of mass of the two ends of the pendulum.

I feel like I did that, no? All of my forces in my free body diagram are originating from the two center of masses.

There is one center of mass, not two.

Ah I see. So, because there is no external force acting on the cartpole in the horizontal direction, the x-coordinate of the center of mass must stay the same. Therefore, the ball and cart must move in opposite directions to counteract each other. Is that right?

If the rod were not there, the ball would fall straight down.   But the rod constrains the ball to be a certain distance from the pivot point.
Since falling straight down would bring the ball too close, the rod is in compression, not tension.   The ends of the rods are pushing on the objects, not pulling.

Ah, I see. I was imagining the rod needed to pull in on the ball to keep the circular path, but it makes sense that it needs to push on it to make sure it follows the circumference. Thank you!
